# Is there a restriction on the number of suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'm mass removing tags from question titles, and sometimes the site hangs for some time, and I have to reload the page to continue. I'm worrying if it's the site's way of telling me that's enough suggested edits per time period. Is there any kind of system that may act like that? Is it okay to go on a suggested edit spree?

Comment: I don't think there's an actual limit.  Just make sure this "spree" is very constructive, as people have to review each request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, when you're suggesting edits you should be fixing entire posts, not just making small little edits such as removing tags from titles while ignoring all of the other problems with a given post.  Such edits are likely to be rejected as "too minor".

It's also not a good idea to suggest a large number of edits at the same time; it results in flooding the homepage and /active tab of the related tags with all of your edits.

Technically though, there is no limit to the number of pending suggested edits from a given user, or a number of suggested edits per day.  There is a queue of suggested edits pending review, and that queue has a max size of 200, but it's nowhere near that limit now, and hasn't been for (to the best of my knowledge) over a year.

If you have a certain number of edits rejected within a given period of time you will end up banned from suggesting edits for a week, which may end up happening if you suggest a lot of minor edits.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that max size.  If nearly the whole queue is ever filled with removals of tag edits and/or "thanks", then there's a problem.

Comment: @Jamal what kind of problem? Minor reviews or low quality questions?

Comment: @user1306322: Minor edits.  For low-quality questions, chances are that a high-rep user will edit it directly.  If not, then a suggested edit would be best.  Such questions should have multiple areas needing an edit.

Comment: I guess I'll take my chances then. Not many of my edits get rejected (for good or bad reasons), and it doesn't seem like I'm doing more harm than good like this.

Comment: @user1306322: As long as you're not getting a lot of rejections, then there's no need to worry.  If it happens to be the *reviews* accepting minor edits (in general), then that's different.

Comment: @user1306322 You have quite a few bad edits, looking at your recent history.  That some of them are incorrectly accepted is unfortunate (some of them are appropriate though, that's true).  You have quite a few invalid edits in which you're removing a word from a title that happens to also be a tag, but that is used naturally within that title, thus making the title senseless.  You also have quite a few minor edits.  You should stop suggesting minor edits, rather than just hoping that most of them get approved.